# Expose a looped changing python variable to QML

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am trying to take a python variable and use it within QML. My implementation is creating a button, which when clicked, will take data generated from my program and append the float values to x and y of a line series. Any suggestions?

Here is a little code from my program that will replicate my issue:

```py
# ========================================================================  #
from math import exp


class ErrorFunction:
    def firstPoint(self, param):
        if param < 0:
            return -self.firstPoint(-param)
        else:
            p = 0.47047
            a = [0.3480242, -0.0958798, 0.7478556]
            t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p * param)
            return 1 - t * (a[0] + t * (a[1] + t * a[2])) * exp(-(param ** 2))

    def successivePoint(self, param):
        return 1 - self.firstPoint(param)
# ========================================================================  #
```

```py
# ========================================================================  #
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

from ErrorFunction import ErrorFunction


class ErrorFunctionRunnable:
    def __init__(self):
        errorfunction = ErrorFunction()
        n = 100
        errorPoints = [(0, 0)] * n
        for i in range(n):
            x = i * 0.1 - 5.0
            errorPoints[i] = (errorfunction.firstPoint(x), errorfunction.successivePoint(x))
            print(errorPoints[i])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "gui.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# ========================================================================  #
```

```py
// ========================================================================  #
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtCharts 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 780
    title: qsTr("QML Test")
    Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox
        width: 114
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 8
            y: 0
            width: 74
            height: 48
            text: qsTr("E_r")
            font.pointSize: 10
            Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade100)
            Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade800)
            onClicked: {
                line.removeAllSeries()
                /*
                Run the "ErrorFunctionRunnable" init function to generate "errorPoints"
                */
            }
        }
    }

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 75

        ChartView {
            id: line
            dropShadowEnabled: false
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
            antialiasing: true

            backgroundColor: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)
            LineSeries {
                name: "Marshak Wave"
                /*
                Update the line series with the points from "errorPoints"
                */
            }
        }
    }

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox1
        y: 704
        height: 76
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0


    }

}
// ========================================================================  #
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can show. I've deleted all of my attempts at exposing a python variable to QML because they obviously didn't work.

Comment: The first code segment is pretty self-explanatory. All it's doing is adding floats to the plot points array.

Comment: This project has thousands of lines of code to produce these plot points. It's far from just a random number generator. This is a scientific program that takes mathematical equations and runs test sequences of the behavior of certain temperatures and gasses within a heated tube to produce a chart displaying the Marshak Waves

Comment: The QML bit I posted is just an example of what I want, but hard coded instead.

Comment: Okay I understand, Give me a moment to write something

Comment: Alright I made a fully functional example of what I'm trying to do. Take a look at the QML class under the onClicked event and under the Line series. Those are the parts that I'm confused with.

Comment: When the onCLicked event is called, I'm wanting it to run the "ErrorFunctionRunnable" class init function.

Comment: that is 100% correct.

Comment: Updated the test QML File to make more sense. Also fixed a brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a QObject that exposes the QPointF list through a method to QML, in addition the limits of the axes must be updated as shown below:

```py
import math
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QPointF, Slot
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication


class ErrorFunction:
    def firstPoint(self, param):
        if param < 0:
            return -self.firstPoint(-param)
        else:
            p = 0.47047
            a = [0.3480242, -0.0958798, 0.7478556]
            t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p * param)
            return 1 - t * (a[0] + t * (a[1] + t * a[2])) * math.exp(-(param ** 2))

    def successivePoint(self, param):
        return 1 - self.firstPoint(param)


class Bridge(QObject):
    @Slot(result="QVariantList")
    def produce(self):
        f = ErrorFunction()
        values = []
        n = 100
        for i in range(n):
            x = i * 0.1 - 5.0
            p = QPointF(f.firstPoint(x), f.successivePoint(x))
            values.append(p)
        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    bridge = Bridge()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("bridge", bridge)

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "gui.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtCharts 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 780
    title: qsTr("QML Test")
    Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox
        width: 114
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 8
            y: 0
            width: 74
            height: 48
            text: qsTr("E_r")
            font.pointSize: 10
            Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade100)
            Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade800)
            onClicked: {
                line.removePoints(0, line.count)
                var x_min = line.axisX.min
                var x_max = line.axisX.max
                var y_min = line.axisY.min
                var y_max = line.axisY.max

                var values = bridge.produce()
                for(var i in values){
                    line.append(values[i].x, values[i].y)
                    x_min = Math.min(x_min, values[i].x)
                    x_max = Math.max(x_max, values[i].x)
                    y_min = Math.min(y_min, values[i].y)
                    y_max = Math.max(y_max, values[i].y)
                }
                line.axisX.min = x_min
                line.axisX.max = x_max
                line.axisY.min = y_min
                line.axisY.max = y_max
            }
        }
    }

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox2
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottomMargin: 75

        ChartView {
            id: view
            dropShadowEnabled: false
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 0
            theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
            antialiasing: true

            backgroundColor: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)
            LineSeries {
                id: line
                name: "Marshak Wave"
            }
        }
    }
    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox1
        y: 704
        height: 76
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    }
}
```

[image]

The disadvantage is the for-loop in QML if the data has many elements, a possible optimization is to use the replace method but it is not accessible in QML so the element has to be exported to python:

```py
import math
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QPointF, Slot
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


class ErrorFunction:
    def firstPoint(self, param):
        if param < 0:
            return -self.firstPoint(-param)
        else:
            p = 0.47047
            a = [0.3480242, -0.0958798, 0.7478556]
            t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p * param)
            return 1 - t * (a[0] + t * (a[1] + t * a[2])) * math.exp(-(param ** 2))

    def successivePoint(self, param):
        return 1 - self.firstPoint(param)


class Bridge(QObject):
    @Slot(QtCharts.QAbstractSeries)
    def fill(self, series):
        axis_x = series.property("axisX")
        axis_y = series.property("axisY")
        xmin = axis_x.min()
        xmax = axis_x.max()
        ymin = axis_y.min()
        ymax = axis_y.max()
        f = ErrorFunction()
        values = []
        n = 100
        for i in range(n):
            x = i * 0.1 - 5.0
            xi = f.firstPoint(x)
            yi = f.successivePoint(x)
            p = QPointF(xi, yi)
            xmin = min(xmin, xi)
            xmax = max(xmax, xi)
            ymin = min(ymin, yi)
            ymax = max(ymax, yi)
            values.append(p)
        series.replace(values)
        axis_x.setMin(xmin)
        axis_x.setMax(xmax)
        axis_y.setMin(ymin)
        axis_y.setMax(ymax)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    bridge = Bridge()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("bridge", bridge)

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "gui.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtCharts 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 780
    title: qsTr("QML Test")
    Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox
        width: 114
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 8
            y: 0
            width: 74
            height: 48
            text: qsTr("E_r")
            font.pointSize: 10
            Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade100)
            Material.background: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade800)
            onClicked: {
                bridge.fill(line)
            }
        }
    }

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox2
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottomMargin: 75

        ChartView {
            id: view
            dropShadowEnabled: false
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 0
            theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
            antialiasing: true

            backgroundColor: Material.color(Material.Grey, Material.Shade900)
            LineSeries {
                id: line
                name: "Marshak Wave"
            }
        }
    }
    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox1
        y: 704
        height: 76
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 114
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    }
}
```